# No package 'pygobject-3.0' found

Tags: linux, package, fedora

I want to install Accerciser
my OS is fedora 16
I downloaded the package,
'cd' into the folder
and run './configure'
and get

```
checking for PYGOBJECT... no
configure: error: Package requirements (pygobject-3.0 >= PYGOBJECT_REQUIRED) were not met:

No package 'pygobject-3.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables PYGOBJECT_CFLAGS and PYGOBJECT_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

however, I checked
it seems I have installed pygobject 3
how to deal with this problem?
thanks!

```
[root@kit accerciser-3.5.3]# rpm -qa|grep "pygobject"
pygobject2-codegen-2.28.6-2.fc16.x86_64
pygobject3-3.0.3-1.fc16.x86_64
pygobject2-devel-2.28.6-2.fc16.x86_64
pygobject2-2.28.6-2.fc16.x86_64
pygobject2-doc-2.28.6-2.fc16.x86_64
```

Comment: should be migrated to SuperUser http://superuser.com/

Comment: Very useful question (solved my issue) -- should be moved to the proper site, then opened again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Install the `pygobject3-devel` package.

Comment: I encountered this issue when compiling the latest mypaint. I needed to  apt-get install the ```python-gobject-dev``` package.

Comment: on ubuntu 16.04: `sudo apt install -y python-gi-dev`

Comment: `python-gi-dev` works on Debian too (as expected).

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 18. pygobject3-devel does not exist. Neither does pygobject3-dev.

Comment: I tried to install python-gi-dev and it promptly installed python 2.7 on my system. This is antique. I don't want it. Ditto for python-gobject-2-dev which is the replacement for python-gobject-dev. These comments are all from this year, why do they refer to such out of date python versions?

Comment: I checked the dependencies of `python-gi-dev` using `apt-cache dotty python-gi-dev` on Ubuntu 20.04, and I don't see references to python 2.7. Installing `python-gi-dev` resolved the "pygobject-3.0" not found.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 `sudo apt install -y python-gi-dev` solved this, thanks.

Comment: `sudo apt install python-gi-dev` also solves on Ubuntu 20.04 (Elementary OS 6)

Comment: yeah.... `python-gi-dev` is the package...